# How to read in from a file and output to another array from the buffer

Tags: c, arrays, file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
 {

    FILE *ptr_file;
    char buff [100];
    char word [100];
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int g=0;
    char a;


    ptr_file = fopen ("input.txt", "r");

    if (!ptr_file)
    printf("File read error");


    while(fscanf(ptr_file, "%s ", buff, &a) != EOF)
    {

          if (isalpha(buff[i]))
            {   
                word[j] = buff[i];
                j++;
                i++;

            }
            else 
            {
                i++;
            }

            printf("%s \n", word);

    }




    fclose(ptr_file);
    return 0;


}
```

Hi I'm trying to write a function that reads in a file line by line using fscanf(), the text is read into a buffer char array, this is then checked character by character as it is read in to see if the character read in is a alphabetical character, i.e. a letter, if so it is added to another array called word.

I have two incrementors, if the character is alphabetical then both are incremented other only the incrementor on buff is incremented, this allows me to skip past none alphabetical characters.

In my head this should logically work however I when I try to print the word array im getting really weird outputs. 
The original file reads

```
Line 1 rgargarg.
Line 2 agragargarrrrrrr.
Line 3 rrrrrrrrrrrr.
Line 4 agragarga.
gOOdbye.
```

the output after the function should be

```
Line  rgargarg
Line  agragargarrrrrrr
Line  rrrrrrrrrrrr
Line  agragarga
gOOdbye
```

the actual output is-

```
L 
L 
La 
Lae 
Lae 
Laea 
Laear 
Laearg 
Laeargr 
Laeargrr� 
Laeargrrr 
Laeargrrrr 
Laeargrrrr
```

I have been trying to get this to work for a while and just cannot see how to get it to function as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually need to scan the input string with a loop.

See the fixed code below, along with comments.

Note that the code makes two assumptions: input strings are null terminated. Input string and **word** string can't be longer than 100 characters (considering the null termination).

The latter is quite dangerous as if not respected result in buffer overrun an memory corruption.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
 {

    FILE *ptr_file;
    char buff [100];
    char word [100];
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int g=0;
    char a;


    ptr_file = fopen ("input.txt", "r");

    if (!ptr_file)
    printf("File read error");


    while(fscanf(ptr_file, "%s ", buff, &a) != EOF)
    {
        i=0;
        j=0;
        word[0]=0;
        while(buff[i]!=0) // assuming the lines you're reading are null terminated string
        {

          if (isalpha(buff[i]))
            {   
                word[j] = buff[i];
                j++;
                i++;

            }
            else 
            {
                i++;
            }
        }

        word[j]=0;    // this ensures word is a null terminated string

        printf("%s \n", word);

    }




    fclose(ptr_file);
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: You can change `word[j+1] = 0` to `word[j] = '\0'` and move it right above the `printf`, and the `else` branch can be removed since `i++` is done in either case.

Comment: I implemented your could and it seems to work, howeever in the output im getting spaces more than \n would provide between my words.

Comment: I ended up using another method using pointers, however this did work, but when I tried to read in a large file it couldn't get all the way through it, but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't resetting either of the counters (`i` or `j`) anywhere, and you are not iterating over `buff` before reading into it again, and you are not terminating `word` with a NUL character (zero) before you print it.

(Also, not directly related, but your `buff` will overflow if the input string is longer than 100 characters.)

Answer (score 0):

Well you only have a single dimension array for word in your code. According to you , you want an array of strings. And also fscanf will overwrite your buffer for every line. Here is a code that does what you want(I have modified your code)

```
int main()
{

FILE *ptr_file;
char buff [100];
char word [100][100];
int i=0;
int j=0;
int k=0;
int g=0;
char a;


ptr_file = fopen ("input.txt", "r");

if (!ptr_file)
printf("File read error");


while(fscanf(ptr_file, "%s ", buff, &a) != EOF)
{

    i=0;j=0;
    while(buf[i]!='\0'){
      if (isalpha(buff[i]))
        {   
            word[k][j] = buff[i];
            j++;
            i++;

        }
        i++;
    }
    word[k][j]='\0';
    printf("%s \n", word[k]);
    k++;

}




fclose(ptr_file);
return 0;


}
```

Comment: no this is what I want, the words are going to be read in and added to a binary tree word by word once they have been fixed.

Comment: In that case, change word to a single dimension as in your code and remove the index `k`(i.e replace `word[k]` by `word` ).Also sorry for the mistake, remove `i++` inside the if condition. You should get what you want.